# Swift Date Picker hide days of the week

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I use standard Apple UIDatePicker with **inline** style. How can I hide the days of the week?
I did not find the method on the Internet

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odpyy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change the `Mode` from `Attributes Inspector` ? By default the mode is set to `Date and Time`. You need to change it from there or you can create your own CustomDatePicker to display only the months or only the years.
Take a look to this CustomDatePicker example here:
https://github.com/Anandsan/UICustomDatePicker

Or you can use a `UIPickerView` to set all the months and another `UIPickerView` to set the years you want to display and after that you can extract the selected values and to use them in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I need to hide the line with the days of the week as in the screenshot below. As far as I understand based on your answer, this cannot be done and it is necessary to create a custom datePicker?

Comment: Yes, or you can add 2 x UIPickerViews on your storyboard and will be more easy and fast for you.